# Hibernate criteria with projection doesn't return the entity on which criteria is implemented

Tags: hibernate, spring, criteria

I'm using spring-hibernate and using HibernateDAOSupport class.
I have two tables mapped to each other in one-to-many fashion.
I'm implementing the below criteria

```
 DetachedCriteria criteria = getCriteria( "a" )
        .setProjection( Projections.projectionList()
                .add( Projections.groupProperty("a.id" ) )
                .add( Projections.count( "a.id" ), "count" )
                )
        .createCriteria( "huApps", "hu")
        .addOrder( Order.desc( "count" ) )
        ;
```

this works well and create the below query

```
select
        this_.id as y0_,
        count(this_.id) as y1_ 
    from
        apps this_ 
    inner join
        huapps huapp1_ 
            on this_.id=huapp1_.appid 
    group by
        this_.id 
    order by
        y1_ desc
```

In result, it returns a list of `object[]`. But I want that it should return `List<App>`(App is the class on which I implemented/created the criteria).
I want that it would create the query

```
select
 this_
    from
        apps this_ 
    inner join
        huapps huapp1_ 
            on this_.id=huapp1_.appid 
    group by
        this_.id 
    order by
        y1_ desc
```

Please help me in writing the correct criteria.
I also tried with `sqlProjection()` but even that didn't work.
Is there any way I can achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

You try to add orger for new critheria that is result of function `detachedCriteria.createCriteria("huApps", "hu")`. This function return the new criteria for class of huApp property.

Try to replace you criteria like this:

```
DetachedCriteria detachedCriteria = DetachedCriteria.forClass(A.class);
detachedCriteria.setProjection(Projections.projectionList()
            .add(Projections.groupProperty("id"))
            .add(Projections.count("id"), "count")
    );

detachedCriteria.createCriteria("huApps", "hu");
detachedCriteria.addOrder(Order.desc("count"));

List<A> list = detachedCriteria.getExecutableCriteria(getSession()).list();
```

It works well for me.

Comment: Again creating the same query  select
        this_.id as y0_,
        count(this_.id) as y1_ 
    from
        ChleonCloudVault.apps this_ 
    inner join
        ChleonCloudVault.huapps huapp1_ 
            on this_.id=huapp1_.appid 
    group by
        this_.id 
    order by
        y1_ desc

Comment: How do you generate this sql? 
This string of code `detachedCriteria.getExecutableCriteria(getSession()).list()`return the instance of `List` class but I specify the generic of needed type

Comment: Yes that returns a List<Object[]>. Every element of the list contains an array of Object(each of size 2). at index=0, id and at index=1, count for that app. And the provided sql is generated by Hibernate.

Comment: Oh! Maybe I should wear glasses. I'm so sorry for my inattention.

But you can not provide your desired request in sql. Sql can get you only field on which you grouping or some aggregation functions like max or count. So result that you get is not hibernate limitation. 

Your desired request in sql looks like this: 
`SELECT a.* FROM A_TABLE a
INNER JOIN (SELECT field, count(*) as score from A_TABLE GROUP BY field) b
     ON a.field = b.field
ORDER BY b.score`

So you must use sub-query for inner select.

Answer (score 1):

Try calling

```
DetachedCriteria criteria = getCriteria( "a" )
    .setProjection( Projections.projectionList()
    .add( Projections.groupProperty("a.id" ), "id" )
            .add( Projections.count( "a.id" ), "count" )
            )
    .createCriteria( "huApps", "hu")
    .addOrder( Order.desc( "count" ) )
    .setResultTransformer(Transformers.aliasToBean(App.class))
```

This should map the properties alias to the fields of the bean that you specify. App will need setters and getters on the appropriate fields